# How to match PATCH WorkItem with corresponding webhook event

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I need to be able to understand is our client was initiator of updating work item.
For example:
Client is updating title for work item:

```
PATCH https://dev.azure.com/baydet/ay/_apis/wit/workitems/1
Content-Type: application/json-patch+json

[
  {
    "op": "add",
    "path": "/fields/System.Title",
    "value": "new title"
  }
]
```

and later it is receiving webhook:

```
{
  "eventType": "workitem.updated",
...
      "System.Title": {
        "oldValue": "old title",
        "newValue": "new title"
      }
...
}
```

What is the best way to understand that this webhook event was caused by our ADO client?
Is there some special header for that?